# file.write() keeps creating/returning an empty file

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write to a file but the code is not working and `write()` keeps returning an empty text file.

```py
with open('UFOGB_Observations.txt', 'r') as UFO_Obsr:
    lines_txt = UFO_Obsr.readlines()
    print('file read')

    #Tell python where a column ends:
    for x in range(0, ):
       UFO_Obsr.split('\t')

    with open ('UFO_Observations_1.txt', 'w+') as UFO_Obsw:
        ##with a for loop, iterating through the rows to
        ##change all instances of html codes(I found a few other html codes!):
        for line in UFO_Obsr: 
            line = line.replace('&#39', "'")
            line = line.replace('&#33', '!')
            line = line.replace('&amp;', '&')
            UFO_Obsw.write(line)
    print('File written')
```

Comment: This is because after you did `lines_txt = UFO_Obsr.readlines()` the file pointer is now in the end of the file. So when you do `for line in UFO_Obsr:` nothing happens and the loop doesn't run even one time -> so nothing is written to the file

Comment: Have you tried to print the values of the variable line after each .replace() ?

Comment: `UFO_Obsr.readlines()` empties the file handle. Did you mean to use `lines_txt`? `for line in lines_txt:` I would suggest doing `for line in [line.split('\t') for line in lines_txt]: ...`

Comment: @cocool97 yes, I did, that part seems to work ok though

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy Thank you. I didn't try that... see, I'm new to coding  : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #Tell python where a column ends:
    for x in range(0, ):
       UFO_Obsr.split('\t')
```

doesn't do anything so I'll leave it out.

---

For each line of the original file, write to the new file after modifying.

```
with open('UFOGB_Observations.txt', 'r') as UFO_Obsr, open ('UFO_Observations_1.txt', 'w+') as UFO_Obsw:

    ##with a for loop, iterating through the rows to
    ##change all instances of html codes(I found a few other html codes!):
    for line in UFO_Obsr: 
        line = line.replace('&#39', "'")
        line = line.replace('&#33', '!')
        line = line.replace('&amp;', '&')
        UFO_Obsw.write(line)
    print('File written')
```

Comment: This was great help! Thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over the `lines_txt` instead, you have already reached the end of file by doing the `readlines()` or remove the `lines_txt = UFO_Obsr.readlines()`

Comment: This worked too! Thank you! This was great help : )